# Rewrite SQL query in CTE query

Tags: mysql, mariadb, cte, recursive

I have this table which I would like to store a chain of records.

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
    id INT,
    unique_id varchar,
    reference_id varchar,
);
```

I want to implement SQL query for MariDB which prints all records by id with all records with reference_id. Something like this:

```
| id | unique_id | reference_id |   |   |
|----|-----------|--------------|---|---|
| 43 | 55544     |              |   |   |
| 45 | 45454     | 43           |   |   |
| 66 | 55655     | 45           |   |   |
| 78 | 88877     | 66           |   |   |
| 99 | 454       | 33           |   |   |
```

I would like when I select record 66 to get all up and down transactions because each other are using id which points to them. How I can implement this using Recursive CTE? Is there a better way?

Expected result for record with unique_id 66:

```
| id | unique_id | reference_id |   |   |
|----|-----------|--------------|---|---|
| 43 | 55544     |              |   |   |
| 45 | 45454     | 43           |   |   |
| 66 | 55655     | 45           |   |   |
| 78 | 88877     | 66           |   |   |
```

This SQL query works:

```
select t.id, t.unique_id, @uid := t.reference_id reference_id
from (select * from mytable order by id desc) t
join (select @uid := 66) tmp
where t.id = @uid or reference_id=66
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/33mbBmQRiF5Z8eRoCR3oco/0

But when I tried this CTE query I can't get the above rows.

```
with recursive cte as (
      select t.*
      from mytable t
      where t.id = 66
      union all
      select t.*
      from cte join
           mytable t
           on cte.id = t.reference_id
     )
select *
from cte;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ppmxX12PJ1rhszp85nJcWp/0

Can you give me a hand how to rewrite the SQL query properly, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You have to choose a direction when using the recursive `CTE`. You could add another recursive `CTE` to account for the descending `reference_id`'s**

```
with recursive 
cte as (
      select t.*
      from mytable t
      where t.id = 66
      union all
      select t.*
      from cte join
           mytable t
           on t.id = cte.reference_id
     ),
 cte2 as (
      select t.*
      from mytable t
      where t.id = 66
      union all
      select t.*
      from cte join
           mytable t
           on cte.id = t.reference_id
     )
SELECT *
FROM cte
UNION 
SELECT *
FROM cte2
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

**Result**

```
| id  | unique_id | reference_id |
| --- | --------- | ------------ |
| 43  | 55544     |              |
| 45  | 45454     | 43           |
| 66  | 55655     | 45           |
| 78  | 88877     | 66           |
```

[DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tCLUrkRxunNvLfZ7W9iKRR/0)

**EDIT:**

*added version with UNION ALL*

```
with recursive 
cte as (
      select t.*
      from mytable t
      where t.id = 66
      union all
      select t.*
      from cte join
           mytable t
           on t.id = cte.reference_id
     ),
 cte2 as (
      select t.*
      from mytable t
      where t.reference_id = 66
      union all
      select t.*
      from cte2 join
           mytable t
           on cte2.id = t.reference_id
     )
SELECT * 
FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM cte2
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

[DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sGP5XLXy7hnzgXRdpDZ1AX/0)

Comment: Thanks, I have 2 additional questions: 1 Can I somehow use it in JPA? 2. Do you know what will be the performance impact for very large table?

Comment: Which one will be faster CTE of the first solution with Joins?

Comment: Yes , exactly .

Comment: Unfortunately I use 10.0.36-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 from official Ubuntu repository and I get `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'recursive 
cte as (
      select t.*
      from payment_transactions t
      whe' at line 1`

Comment: I updated MariaDB to version 10.3 and it works! Thanks!